# Checking for normal or wide tile on windows 8 live tile

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm creating a live tile in a windows 8 C# XAML app. I've worked out that I need to use the TileUpdateManager class to get the tile template. I can also see that there are different templates for a normal tile (150x150) and the wide tile (310x150). **So, how can I detect whether the user has chosen to display the normal tile or a wide tile in C# code so that I can get the relevant template?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better approach is to supply both and the OS will work it out.

Here is a good document that outlines how to do this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/16/creating-a-great-tile-experience-part-1.aspx

Comment: The linked blog post also touches on why both wide and square tile content should be provided in each notification.  The user can change the size of the tile at any time, and by providing both, the app need not (and will not) be made aware of the change.